# parsing XML file with "&<" characters when using python lxml

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file, some of it's tags has some characters like "ç". What I want is to extract this tag's text and write into .txt file.

## Here is the xml file look's like:

```
    
<article mdate="2020-04-16" key="journals/tkdd/DuarteGB16">
<author>Jo&atilde;o Duarte</author>
<author orcid="0000-0003-3357-1195">Jo&atilde;o Gama</author>
<author orcid="0000-0002-8339-7773">Albert Bifet</author>
<title>Adaptive Model Rules From High-Speed Data Streams.</title>
<pages>30:1-30:22</pages>
<year>2016</year>
<volume>10</volume>
<journal>ACM Trans. Knowl. Discov. Data</journal>
<number>3</number>
<ee>https://doi.org/10.1145/2829955</ee>
<ee>https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q58204491</ee>
<url>db/journals/tkdd/tkdd10.html#DuarteGB16</url>
</article>
```

## and here is my code in python:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

import os
from pathlib import Path


test_file = "test_data.xml"
file_output_path = "results.txt"


def search_xxx(root, sth: str, file_writer):

    """
    parameter: [sth] can be article、inproceedings、proceedings、book、incollection、phdthesis、mastersthesis、www

    """
    # with open("result.txt", "w") as f:


    item_counter = 0

    for item in root.findall(sth):

        message = []
        invalid = False

        item_counter += 1


        
        # print("-----info---------")
        # article dict["key"] -> key
        key_str = item.attrib["key"] 
        key_str_list = key_str.split('/')
        key = key_str_list[1]

        # print("[Category]: ", key_str)
        message.append(key)
        

        # key_str = item.attrib["key"]
        # message.append(key_str)


        # title
        if item.find("title") != None:
            if item.find("title").text != None:
                title = item.find("title").text

                # print("[Title]: ", title)
                message.append(title)
            else:
                # invalid = True
                continue
        else:
            invalid = True


        # author 
        # print("[Authors]:")
        for item_son in item.iter("author"):
            if item_son.text != None:

                # author = item_son.text
                author = item_son.text
                # print("[author]: ", author)
        

                message.append(author)
            else:
                invalid = True
                break
                
        

        ## write to file
        # print(message)
        # print()

        if invalid == True:
            # message = ""
            file_writer.write("")
        else:

    
            message = "+".join(message)
            

            file_writer.write(message + '\n')
            # print("---------------")
    


# write to txt file.

def main():

    parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
    # tree = ET.parse(test_file, parser=parser)
    tree = ET.parse(dblp_file_path, parser=parser)

    root = tree.getroot()

    with open(file_output_path, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        print("Extracting...")
        
        search_xxx(root, "article", f)

        print("Extract done.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Question: when I run this code and it will get the expected result:

### output: tkdd+Adaptive Model Rules From High-Speed Data Streams.+Jo+Jo+Albert Bifet

### Here comes the question:

#### in XML file,

```
<author>Jo&atilde;o Duarte</author>
<author orcid="0000-0003-3357-1195">Jo&atilde;o Gama</author>
```

I want to get the first author which should be "Joo Duarte", the second should be "Joo Gama",

#### But, the result is "Jo" and "Jo".

## Can someone help me out, PLEASE!

Comment: The XML you are parsing is invalid. You are getting something out of it, but you wish the invalid part of the XML was handled differently. That may be possible, but you should consider feeding a valid XML to the parser for the best results...

Comment: BTW, perhaps a different XML parser would do something closer to what you expect...